# Does the PayPal Vault API support Purchasing/Procurement (P-Cards)?

Tags: paypal, credit-card, paypal-vault

I am looking to add **PayPal Vault** support for an application but can't find in the PayPal documentation as to **whether it support Purchasing/Procurement P-Cards**.

I would just setup a test inside the sandbox and see whether it worked but I am not aware of any test p-card numbers that can be used for this purpose.  Does anyone have any experience using p-cards with the vault API?  I'm using test credit cards from

https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm

but can't find a way to distinguish between normal credit card numbers and p-cards numbers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the P-card.  There are a couple of considerations to bear in mind:

- Does the card have a BIN that corresponds to a card type that PayPal supports (e.g., Visa, MasterCard, American Express, or Discover)?  If not, then the answer is **no**.
- Does the issuer require [Level 2 or Level 3 data](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#about-program-levels) to be provided with each transaction?  If so, then the answer is **no**, as PayPal doesn't support L2 or L3 data on card transactions.  (In my experience, a lot of the P-cards being used by US Government employees require L3 data to be provided.)

Otherwise, you should be OK.